# kubernetes dashboard is not found

Tags: kubernetes

http://10.199.135.36:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui/#/dashboard/

```
{
   "kind": "Status",
   "apiVersion": "v1",
   "metadata": {},
   "status": "Failure",
   "message": "endpoints \"kube-ui\" not found",
   "reason": "NotFound",
   "details": {
      "name": "kube-ui",
      "kind": "endpoints"
   },
   "code": 404
}
```

Comment: Did you create it? You need to create it using the yml

Comment: What did you do to try to figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In the newer version of kubernetes,dashboard is a alternative solution for kube-ui.Using endpoint named `kube-ui` may lead to `endpoints \"kube-ui\" not found`(404).To solve this problem,you can choose an new endpoint named `kubernetes-dashboard`.For more details,see:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/

All in all,if you use kube-ui(example:v3),the automatic redirection maybe not correct and the 404 error appears because of the unlocation of the resources.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a 10-dot ip which is only routable within your cluster, so I'm going to assume you're eg: curling that url from a node.

Please debug the service and report as to what fails: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-services/, I'm guessing `kubectl --namespace=kube-system get ep kube-ui` shows nothing.

Comment: [root@test-ops-node1 pods]# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system        
NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.1-mhz6w   1/1       Running   0          8m
kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.1-pylco   1/1       Running   0          14m

Comment: "kubectl --namespace=kube-system get ep kube-ui"
Error from server: endpoints "kube-ui" not found

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes-UI is addon. You can create it in **Ubuntu** follow this link
http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/
on **Deploy addons** section.

Answer (score 0):

```
dashboard-controller.yaml
dashboard-service.yaml

standard configure file

...
 kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        #image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-ui:v3
        **image: index.tenxcloud.com/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.0.1**
        resources:
...
```

after run and test logs info such as

```
[root@test-ops-node1 pods]# kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.1-mhz6w --namespace=kube-system
2016/05/20 08:54:10 Starting HTTP server on port 9090
2016/05/20 08:54:10 Creating API server client for http://localhost:8080
2016/05/20 08:54:10 Creating in-cluster Heapster client
2016/05/20 09:09:56 Incoming HTTP/1.1 GET /api/v1/replicationcontrollers request from 172.17.80.0:39277
2016/05/20 09:09:56 Getting list of all replication controllers in the cluster
2016/05/20 09:09:56 Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/replicationcontrollers: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
2016/05/20 09:09:56 Outcoming response to 172.17.80.0:39277 with 500 status code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your service name or namespace in `dashboard.yaml`, you should change your URL:

```
http://cluster_ip_address:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/modify-namespace/services/modify-service-name/#/dashboard/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).